# Keep getting no route matches for edit. Tried using "edit", now :update and still no luck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"update", 
:controller=>"text_posts"}):

<h1><%= text_post.blog %></h1>
<%= form_tag do %>
<%= link_to "New Text Post", controller: "text_posts", action: "new" %>
<%= link_to "Edit", controller: "text_posts", action: "update" %>
<%= link_to "Delete", controller: "text_posts", action: "destroy" %>
<% end %>
<span class='likes pull-left'>


new_image_link GET     /image_links/new(.:format)      image_links#new

edit_image_link GET    /image_links/:id/edit(.:format) image_links#edit

image_link GET         /image_links/:id(.:format)      image_links#show

PATCH                 /image_links/:id(.:format)      image_links#update

PUT                   /image_links/:id(.:format)      image_links#update

DELETE               /image_links/:id(.:format)      image_links#destroy

text_posts GET       /text_posts(.:format)           text_posts#index

POST                 /text_posts(.:format)           text_posts#create

new_text_post GET    /text_posts/new(.:format)       text_posts#new

edit_text_post GET    /text_posts/:id/edit(.:format)  text_posts#edit

text_post GET         /text_posts/:id(.:format)       text_posts#show

PATCH                 /text_posts/:id(.:format)       text_posts#update

PUT                   /text_posts/:id(.:format)       text_posts#update

DELETE               /text_posts/:id(.:format)       text_posts#destroy
```

Comment: The index.html.erb is :
     <h1>Text Here</h1>
     <% @text_posts.each do |text_post| %>
     <%= div_for text_post do %>
     <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10">
     <h2><%= text_post.title %></h2>
     <h5><%= text_post.url %></h5>
     <h1><%= text_post.blog %></h1>
     <%= form_tag do %>
     <%= link_to "New Text Post", controller: "text_posts", action: "new" %>
     <%= link_to "Edit", controller: "text_posts", action: "update" %>
     <%= link_to "Delete", controller: "text_posts", action: "destroy" %>
     <% end %>

Comment: ext_posts GET    /text_posts(.:format)         text_posts#index
                   POST   /text_posts(.:format)        text_posts#create       
new_text_post GET    /text_posts/new(.:format)   text_posts#new
 edit_text_post GET    /text_posts/:id/edit(.:format)  text_posts#edit
 text_post GET    /text_posts/:id(.:format)      text_posts#show
                    PATCH  /text_posts/:id(.:format)    text_posts#update  PUT    /text_posts/:id(.:format)    text_posts#update
                         DELETE /text_posts/:id(.:format)           text_posts#destroy

Comment: I am sorry if this looks messy! First time asking.

Comment: Why the comments?, you can edit your question to add new information

Comment: It kept stopping me from putting in everything because of formatting.

Comment: You need to use the code formatting to escape all of that. Put 4 spaces before each of the lines. No one wants to try to decipher that stuff from the comments.

Comment: Just added the 4 spaces! Thank you.

Comment: I cleaned it up some. Be sure to use the preview that is created below the area where you enter your question. It will show you how it will look when you post. Sometimes it helps to add some extra line breaks and spaces to give things room and make things line up.

Comment: Thank you again. It now looks legible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this .................

```
<h1><%= text_post.blog %></h1>
<%= link_to "New Text Post", new_text_post_path %>
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_text_post_path(text_post) %>
<%= link_to "Delete", text_post_path(text_post), method: :delete %>
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: @Michelle G : You don't need to add form_tag for links.

Comment: After changing the code, now the delete only renders to show. More hours of trying to figure this out! Thanks everyone for your kindness and help. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
<%= link_to "Edit",  edit_text_post_path(text_post) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Since you use resources in your routes.rb(according to the routes your provided). If you want to go to the edit page, it's better to use the path helper, remember to provide the text_post you want to edit in the argument:

`<%= link_to "Edit",  edit_text_post_path(text_post) %>`

`<%= link_to "Delete",  text_post_path(text_post), :method => :delete %>`

2. The way you wrote is when you have something define in your routes.rb like this:

`match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))', :via => :all`

Even so, you still have to give it the text_post you want to edit because it requires an id in the end of the url. So it should be like:

`<%= link_to 'Edit', :controller => 'text_posts', :action => 'edit', :id => text_post %>`

`<%= link_to 'Delete', :controller => 'text_posts', :action => 'destroy', :id => text_post %>`

3. You don't need to wrap the links into a form_tag.

Hope it helps.